# Final Step for ROS installation failing

Tags: ros, installation, macosx, catkin-make-isolated, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running this command:

```
~/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

Crashes with at this point:

```
cd /Users/Raaj/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/pcl_ros && /Users/Raaj/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake -vd /Users/Raaj/ros_catkin_ws/src/perception_pcl/pcl_ros -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/Raaj/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/pcl_ros -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/Raaj/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

with this :

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/pcl-1.8/PCLConfig.cmake:49 (message):
  simulation is required but glew was not found
```

I've already installed glew via brew install glew. How may I solve this? I am using OSX Mavericks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194736/final-step-for-ros-installation-failing/) by [soulslicer](https://answers.ros.org/users/20426/soulslicer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-10-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-10-10**:
Please link to the instructions you are following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ah it's ok, it seems OSX Mavericks has removed GLEW. I installed it and linked it correctly and it works

---

Originally posted by [soulslicer](https://answers.ros.org/users/20426/soulslicer/) with karma: 61 on 2014-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kpax77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21348/kpax77/) on 2015-01-23**:
And how did you do it if it was already installed via brew ?